# Android service background

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an `Activity` that calls `startService()` in the `onCreate()` with some params.
The Service works well (I use a `Timer`) but when I quit the Activity (`onPause() or  onDestroy()`) what happens is that the  Service is **recreated**! It calls onCreate then onStartCommand() with a null intent! (normal)
So how should I do to retrien the old intent?!
I think there's `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` but how to use it! Is this the right way?

PS: Why the is the Service killed although it `extends` Service? Does it depend on Lifecycle of the activity => so who called him again?

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if(intent != null){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null)

            {
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Action(),15000 , 15000);
            }
        }

        Action() {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Action(),15000 , 15000);  
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you canceled the timer on closing of Activity? Timer runs on different thread may causing this issue. try cancelling the timer on closing of Activity by

    `your_timer_object.Cancel();`

Comment: What code you have written in  onStartCommand() on return of the method. Have you returning "return START_STICKY". If yes , then service will restart it self. You have to call stopSelf() or stopService(Intent service)

Comment: @VipinSharma the timer still work even i quit the apps ! but maybe in short time it canceled or somthings other !

Comment: what i noticed that the object timer recreated also ! 
what should i do to make one instance running all the time ?

Comment: @Rollno1 the service should not be restarted by itself ! because it have params to work with !

Comment: @Rollno1 like you say but in my role i wan't that the service restart so we need to call return START_NOT_STICKY then its works ... THANKS shabeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found the solution and it maybe simple for some, so with reading this: [START_STICKY](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html) and [START_NOT_STICKY](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html)  and that we won't the service restart itself we should return on the onCommand method  START_NOT_STICKY

```
        @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO
  return START_NOT_STICKY ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use intentService instead of service